MoEngage sent Push Notification to my App are being de-prioritized in Android
In my Unity app i have push notifications displayed which are sent from MoEngage.
The issue is, compared to other apps on the phone like MsTeams, AngelOne etc, whose notifications are getting a higher priority meaning they stack above my apps notifications.
So i am trying to figure if this is something to do with the way App works or some setting in app that we change or something to with the System which sending the events.
Any idea on this is greatly appreciated
Made a new Firebase App to send a Push notification to my app and there too same behavior happens.
